# Database design for eCommerce Site with filters

Tags: database, database-design, e-commerce

I am doing a project on eCommerce website, but I am unable to figure out, how to design the database schema for it. In this website, there will be products from several categories and each category has a unique set of filters for it.

Example: The 'Laptop' category has filters such as 'RAM', 'Hard disk', 'Graphics Card', whereas, in the 'Shirt' category filter is 'Fabric Type' and many more.

I have thought of 2 different schema, but I am not sure of which one to be used.

**Design #1**

```
categories
---------
id
category
filters (Here filters will be stored as hard-coded JSON)

products
--------
id
category_id
name
price
specifications (Stored as JSON which will be filters using values from categories.filters)
```

**Design #2**

```
categories
----------
id
category
table_name

products
--------
id
category_id
name
price

laptops
-------
id
product_id
ram
hard_disk

shirts
------
id
product_id
fabric
sleeve
```

Which design should I choose? or is there any better design for it?

**EDIT**

Here, my problem is not about multiple categories but, to integrate filters. For example if I check 'RAM 4 GB' in Laptop category, then it should show all products from Laptop category with 4 GB RAM. I can't make one table for each filter, or category as there will be more than 100 of them.

Comment: It is hard to tell what the relationships between the various tables in design #2 are.  But I don't like your using JSON in design #1.  Try to keep your database relational.

Comment: That's what I also don't like about the design #1. But in design #2 I have to create lots of tables defining each category. There may be hundreds of categories.

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem here.  Why not just add a new column to `products` which will contain the "filters"?  After all, a filter (e.g. RAM) is just another product.

Comment: RAM in the sense of RAM size of Laptop. Filter all laptops with 2GB RAM, 4 GB RAM etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [product with multiple category type database schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011621/product-with-multiple-category-type-database-schema)

Answer (score 2):

I am following @Tim Biegeleisen's design, but rather than putting everything in one table. I modified it to separate categories, products and filters.

```
categories

+----+----------+-----------+
| id | category | parent_id |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 1  | Computer | NULL      |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 2  | Laptop   | 1         |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 3  | Desktop  | 1         |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 4  | Clothing | NULL      |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 5  | T-Shirt  | 4         |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 6  | Shirt    | 4         |
+----+----------+-----------+


products

+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+
| id | category_id | name            | price |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1  | 2           | Acer Aspire     | 600   |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+
| 2  | 3           | Dell All-in-One | 750   |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+
| 3  | 6           | Lee Marc Shirt  | 50    |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+
| 4  | 5           | Nike T-Shirt    | 100   |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+


filters

+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
| id | filter      | value           | product_id | category_id |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
| 1  | RAM         | 4 GB            | 1          | 2           |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
| 2  | Battery     | Li-ion          | 1          | 2           |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
| 3  | HDD         | 500 GB          | 1          | 2           |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
| 4  | RAM         | 16 GB           | 2          | 3           |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
| 5  | HDD         | 1 TB            | 2          | 3           |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
| 6  | Fabric      | Cotton          | 3          | 6           |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
| 7  | Sleeve      | Full            | 3          | 6           |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
| 8  | Size        | M               | 4          | 5           |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
| 9  | Color       | Black           | 4          | 5           |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
```

To get all filters for a category:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `filters`.`filter` FROM `filters` WHERE `filters`.`category_id` = 2
```

To know all available RAM sizes for Laptop category:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `filters`.`value` FROM `filters` WHERE `filters`.`category_id` = 2 AND `filters`.`filter`='RAM'
```

`category_id` in `filters` table can be excluded as we can get that from `products` table. I have added it because every time I have to get all filters, I don't have to get through `products` table.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach your problem by treating your entire catalog as a *tree*, where each record represents a relationship between a parent category and a child category/product.

Products:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id |   name    | child_id  |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | laptops   |   2       |
| 1  | laptops   |   6       |
| 2  | RAM       |   3       |
| 2  | RAM       |   4       |
| 2  | RAM       |   5       |
| 3  | RAM - 1GB |   null    |
| 4  | RAM - 2GB |   null    |
| 5  | RAM - 4GB |   null    |
| 6  | hard disk |   null    |
| 7  | shirts    |   8       |
| 8  | fabrics   |   null    |
| 9  | desktops  |   2       |
| 9  | desktops  |   6       |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

The "root" categories are those which have no parents.  Here is how you would query all the root categories:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name)
FROM Products
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT child_id FROM Products)
```

Using my contrived example this would return three id values, 1, 7, and 9, for laptops, shirts, and desktops, respectively.  If you then wanted to get all parts for laptops you could use this query:

```
SELECT child_id FROM Products WHERE id = 1
```

This would return 2 and 6 for the RAM and hard disk categories.  You can continue querying deeper into the tree as needed.  For example, if you wanted to get all RAM *products*, you could do this query:

```
SELECT id, name FROM Products WHERE id IN (3,4,5) AND child_id IS NULL
```

Note carefully the use of `IS NULL` to identify that the record be a product and not a category, since it has no more children.

I believe that even massive e-commerce sites like Amazon and Overstock do not have a hierarchy which is more than 5-10 levels, even in the deepest cases.

Comment: Now I'm doing same thing for categories and sub categories. I am putting all categories into `categories` table, then for sub-categories I'm putting parent_id just like you have done. And even if I make the way you proposed, how I'm going to store data for all ram sizes those are available?

Comment: How many records do you expect?  A few hundred thousand should not be an issue with the proper indices in place.  Just keep creating levels in the hierarchy until you reach the bottom.

Comment: ~1million records in product table.

Comment: If you expect the number of products to be constant at one million, then I would personally try my approach first.

Comment: No, it's going to increase. How to store RAM size data, if I follow your approach?