# Table Composition with 3 entities where 1st and 2nd are child of 3rd

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

This is actually one of the things that makes me confused when designing tables and normalizing them. It is when I'm faced to design tables for entities which has sub-types or "child" tables, if you will.

So my entities are **Frame**, **Poster**, **Order**, **OrderItems**.

Considering the following:

A **Frame** `is-a` **Product**

A **Poster** `is-a` **Product**

An **Order** has `one-or-many` **Product**(s) *or items*

So, I thought of two possible ways of designing the tables.

**(Solution 1)**

**frame**

```
frame_id PK
material (can be steel, plastic, wood etc)
price_per_sqft
inStock
image
desc
name
```

**poster**

```
poster_id PK
desc
image
inStock
price_per_sqft
name
category (can be cartoon, horses, and whatnot)
```

**order**

```
order_id PK
items_count
date_ordered
status (delivered, pending, shipped, unshipped, cancelled..)
```

**orderitems** (contains the items in an order# which can be a frame or poster)

```
order_id FK
frame_or_poster_id FK (this is the part im not sure of)
length
width
cost
```

**(Solution 2)** (this DROPS the frame and poster tables and puts in product table)

**product**

```
product_id PK
isPoster BIT
isFrame BIT
inStock BIT
desc
price_per_sqft
material
category
image
name
```

**order**

```
order_id PK
items_count
date_ordered
status (delivered, pending, shipped, unshipped, cancelled..)
```

**orderitems** (contains the items in an order# which can be a frame or poster)

```
order_id FK
product_id FK
length
width
cost
```

Is solution 2 a normalized table design? Solution 2 has a **Product** table which can store either a **Frame** or a **Poster** and identified by `product_id` but the problem with it is

**Null Values**. Not both **Poster** and **Frame** has the `material` or `category` attribute. It means that material and category can be nullable.

If I follow Solution 1, I cannot reference individual `FK` for `frame_id` and `poster_id` under **orderitems** table. That's why I put `frame_or_poster_id` above.

What is the best approach to this? What is the best approach when given 3 entities on which 2 are sub-type of 1. In this case, **Frame** and **Poster** are of type **Product**

I think solution 1 has some redundancies because of repeated columns or attributes.

I'd appreciate any solution or suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that order and desc are both reserved words in MySQL

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, I used the back tick ` but you're right I'll just change it to description.

Comment: "Normalization" is about replacing a table with others with the same columns that join to it. This is not about normalization. A FK involves values for some columns having to be values for another columns. frame_or_poster_id is not a FK. It just reminds you of a FK.

Comment: This is a faq, please google your title and/or your phrase 'design tables for entities which has sub-types or "child" tables"' with 'sql OR database'.

Comment: Thank you for your corrections peeps I'll update the post.

Comment: There may be an answer here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011621/product-with-multiple-category-type-database-schema/32024055#32024055

Comment: Take a look at subtype/supertype like
http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a196713%20subtype

Comment: `frame_or_poster_id FK` is not possible.  Any attempt to do it is so kludgy as to be not worth doing.

Comment: Use `ENUM('poster', 'frame')` instead of two bits.